# How to change table row background-color with css pseudo class :has()?

Tags: html, jquery, css

How to set table row background-color with css pseudo class :has() only when button clicked and class "group-process" added to each row in tbody?

When I click button with id "group_processing_button" displays block with class "group-processing". Also when I click this button only rows which have class i[class$="fa-check-square"] must have `background-color: #9e9;` I mean this css style must work:

```
.table tbody tr[class$="group-process"]:has(td.no):has(i[class$="fa-check-square"]) {
    background-color: #9e9;
}
```

Only when block with class "group-processing" displayed by button.
When I click and display off the block with class "group-processing", rows which have class i[class$="fa-check-square"] must have `background-color: transparent`, this style must not work:

```
.table tbody tr[class$="group-process"]:has(td.no):has(i[class$="fa-check-square"]) {
    background-color: #9e9;
}
```

Thank You for help!

```js
var $groupProcessingContainer = jQuery('.group-processing');
var $groupProcessingTable = jQuery('.table-order');

jQuery('#group_processing_button').click(function() {
  var $rows = $groupProcessingTable.find('tbody tr');
  
  $rows.each(function() {
    var $row = jQuery(this);
    
    if ($row.hasClass('group-process')) {
      $row.removeClass('group-process');
    } else {
      $row.addClass('group-process');
    }
  });
  
  $groupProcessingContainer.slideToggle();
});
```

```css
tr td.no .group-check {
  display: none;
}

tr.group-process td.no .group-check {
  display: inline;
}

.table tbody tr[class$="group-process"]:has(td.no):has(i[class$="fa-check-square"]) {
  background-color: #9e9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" id="group_processing_button">Group processing</button>

<div class="group-processing" style="display: none;">Block for filtering</div>

<table class="iblock table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-order">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Supplier</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="no">1.<i class="fa group-check fa-check-square"></i></td>
      <td>
        <a href="" target="_blank">item_name</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="" target="_blank">Supplier_name</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <td class="no">1.<i class="fa fa-square-o group-check"></i></td>
      <td>
        <a href="" target="_blank">item_name</a>
      </td>
      <td><a href="" target="_blank">Supplier_name</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Good start with this post, but please review it for clarity. Some of the wording is unclear. For example, `Only when block with class "group-processing" displayed by button` is not a complete sentence. I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: I made mistake. Block with class "group-processing" must be displayed off when page is loaded.)

Comment: @isherwood. what did You do? What was the solution? ))) Why did not work the code?

Comment: All I did was format your code into a snippet demo. I made no changes, as you can see in the edit history.

Comment: OK, I found the reason, there were other codes (code which changes bg color) inside the code of My project that I forgot to delete) Thank You!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, then either provide and accept an answer below or delete your question.

Comment: FYI: but should be ok: https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas

Comment: If your question has been resolved outside of SO, please consider closing it